# Is AngularJS parsing the value incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an extremely simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/daylight/hqHSr/

To try it, just go to the fiddle and click the [Add Item] button to add some rows.

Next, click the check box next to any item and you'll see something similar to the following:
[image: AngularBugStep1]

**Problem: Only Displays Numeric Part**
The problem is that the value should display the entire string shown in the row. In the example that means it should display: 86884-LLMUL.
Notice that it only displays the numeric part of the value.

If you look at the control you'll see that I'm using an input of type="text".
Also, if you look at the model (simpleItem) object you'll see that the one property it has is a string.
The JavaScript for the model class looks like:

```
  function simpleItem(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

**My Attempt To Force to String Type**
When I generate each of the simpleItems I even go so far as to set them to a character when I call the constructor (just to force the id to be set to a string type).

Here's the code that initializes each of the simpleItem ids:

```
currentItem.id = getRandom(100000).toString() + "-" + getRandomLetters(5).toUpperCase();
```

You can see the rest of the code in the fiddle, but the thing is I generate a random value and concatenate the value together with a hyphen and 5 letters. It's just a silly little piece of code for this sample.

But now, here is the part where it gets really odd.
If I simply change the hyphen - to another character like an uppercase X I get an error each time I click on the checkbox.
Here's the changed code and the new output, which you can see at the revised fiddle: [fiddle version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/daylight/hqHSr/2/)

```
currentItem.id = getRandom(100000).toString() + "X" + getRandomLetters(5).toUpperCase();
```

[image]

Also, now if you open Dev Tools in your browser you'll see in the console that Angular is now reporting an error each time you click the [Add Item] button.  It looks like:
[image]

**Adding Single-quotes ?Fixes? It**
If you go up to the HTML and alter the following line from this:

```
ng-init="itemId ={{l.id.toString()}}"
```

to this

```
ng-init="itemId ='{{l.id.toString()}}'"
```

Now when you run it, the error will go away and it will work as you can see at the updated fiddle here: [fiddle Version 3](http://jsfiddle.net/daylight/hqHSr/3/)

**Angular : Converts Hyphen to Minus Sign?**
You see, Angular seems to be converting it to a numeric, attempting to do math on it (parsing the hyphen as a minus sign) and then truncating the string portion. That all seems to work when I use a hyphen, but when I use a X then Angular chokes.

Here's what it looks like when you add the single-quotes - of course the angular errors in Dev Tools console go away too.
[image]

**Angular Forces to Numeric Type?**
Why would this occur in Angular?  It's as if it is attempting to force my string value to a numeric even though the INPUT element is type text and the JavaScript var is type string.
Anyone have ideas about this?

**What About the Asterisk (multiplication symbol)?**

Right as I was completing this I wondered what would happen if I changed the - to a * and ran it again.  This time I saw the error below, which is indicative that something is attempting to convert to numeric.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your ng-init with

```
ng-init="itemId =l.id.toString()"
```

In following with the docs, you should only use init in special circumstances anyway, you should rely on your controller for this. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

Comment: That is the exact answer I was wondering about.  I'm learning Angular now and so it took me quite some time to determine how I initialize a variable and along the way I somehow got the syntax incorrect, but it still "worked".  If you can call it that.  Thanks for noticing exactly what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. Angular is merely interpolating the text you have in your scope into the `ng-init` expression [using `scope.$eval`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInit.js#L56) and then executing that expression. This has very little to do with what is the type of the `input` box of the rest of the surrounding context.

It is definitely not desirable that Angular should wrap any interpolation it does in `quotes`, it'll break its use in all other places such as `class="my-class {{dynamic-class}}"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think we're just getting confused with Angular's weirdness.  Basically, you're giving angular a string which it's turning into a javascript expression because it's in a {{}}. It's already, explicitly, a string (between the double-quotes):

> ng-init="itemId ={{l.id.toString()}}"

It's apparently ignoring the fact that you're saying "hey, no really, this is a real string" with your `l.id.toString()`.  It doesn't care.  It's already a string and is going to evaluate it.

Just use the single quotes?

If you `ng-init itemId={{undefined===undefined}}`, what would you expect to happen?  (it prints "true" in the alert).

Same with this: (undefined === undefined is in quotes) `ng-init itemId={{'undefined===undefined'}}`; prints true in the alert.

Comment: Because I'm learning Angular now I was attempting to init my variable and couldn't get it to work properly and fell into thinking I had to add the {{}} directive to do that. That was a mistake on my part, then as I went down that road I became more confused about what was happening.  lex82 and Charlie Brown really hit the answer with explaining that I don't need to use the directive in the ng-init.  It was an interesting side effect though,don't you think?

Comment: For sure.  I'm in a similar boat -- perhaps only about 3 weeks of angular-immersion ahead.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` expects an angular expression. You don't have to use curly brackets there. You can simply write it like this:

```
ng-init="itemId=l.id" ng-click="checkBoxClicked(itemId)"
```